# To what extent can you 'sculpt' your vocal sound?

Tags: voice

I know that it's possible (with the aid of a vocal coach) for someone to learn how to sing better (in terms of accurately hitting notes) and possibly to extend their range; however, I'm wondering to what extent it is possible to mould or 'sculpt' your vocal sound?

For example, I've been practicing singing the lead vocal part for Alice in Chains (with a view to possibly starting a tribute band). I can hit most of the notes ok (although the very highest ones are a bit of a stretch); however, my voice is on the softer side and doesn't really have the edgy grit to it that Layne Staley does. I'm not saying I want to sound exactly like him, but is it possible that a vocal coach could help me sculpt my voice to at least sound more 'rocky'?

Answer (score 1):

I should think the answer is yes, but it would depend upon the coach. Some might not know how, others might think it would be "bad technique" to make a tone grittier and refuse to teach it on that basis.

Proof of concept: Tuvan throat singing can be taught, and that style shows an amazing range of what a person can do to alter the color of the tone. So what you want to accomplish should be physically possible.

Your main task, I think, is going to be about finding the right vocal coach.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Certainly, when I look for a vocal coach, I think it would need to be someone who has experience with hard rock/metal singing, and who understands how to achieve that sort of sound.

Comment: I'd also recommend finding a vocal coach who'll teach you how to achieve that sort of sound without wrecking your voice long-term.